# Tasks roll up to show all pending tasks across all sites in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, tasks, sharepoint-search

Since the "Work Management Service Application" is no more available in SharePoint 2016, any idea how can we perform a tasks roll up to show pending tasks for users, across site collections?

We have a number of workflows running in multiple site collections and sub sites. The Task Aggregation in SharePoint 2013 seemed a perfect solution, however its deprecated in 2016.

Any possible options to achieve similar functionality? Maybe using Search? If so, can you please guide me with the article / configuration / code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible with search.

Since task lists can be created in any SharePoint 2013 site, search can be a useful tool to make sure tasks are not overlooked in large taxonomies. Fortunately, SharePoint 2013’s query builder makes this functionality much easier to implement without the Visual Studio required for matching functionality in SP2010.

Follow this post for reference http://www.surfray.com/blog/2013/06/12/aggregate-your-open-tasks-with-sharepoint-2013/